# MongoDB: adding field to every object in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to add a new field into every object within an array only when that field does not already exist. I am trying to use `updateMany` but the below script does not seem to work... Please help!

```
const updateResult = await Form.updateMany(
  {},
  { $set: { "ss_characteristics.$[elem].new_field": '' } },
  { arrayFilters: [{ "elem.new_field": { $exists: false } }] }
);

console.log('updateResult: ', util.inspect(updateResult, false, null));
// that logs the below:
// updateResult:  { acknowledged: false }
```

```
const all_forms = await Form.find({})

// console.log(all_forms) will give me something like this:
[
  {
    ss_characteristics: [
      { name: 'test 1' },
      { name: 'test 2', new_field: 'No'}
    ]
  },
  {
    ss_characteristics: [
      { name: 'test 3' },
      { name: 'test 4' },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IhNvhy1Aiza) likes your update.  It does what you want, yes?

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code lies in the way you're using the updateMany method with array filters. The updateMany method you're using takes three arguments: the filter, the update, and options. However, you're passing the filter and update as separate arguments instead of combining them into a single object. To remedy your errors, you'll need to modify your code:

> const updateResult = await Form.updateMany(
> {},
> {
> $set: { "ss_characteristics.$[elem].new_field": "" }
> },
> {
> arrayFilters: [{ "elem.new_field": { $exists: false } }]
> }
> );

This change ensures that the filter and update are wrapped within a single object. Now, when you execute updateMany, it should work as intended, adding the new_field only to objects within the ss_characteristics array where it doesn't already exist.

After running the update, you can verify the changes by fetching all the documents again using Form.find({}). The updated all_forms should reflect the modifications you made.

> const all_forms = await Form.find({}); console.log(all_forms);

You should see the new_field added to the appropriate objects within the ss_characteristics array.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect. The syntax for the `updateResult` is good. I am still getting the same error